# Stringex NoMethodError: undefined method `initialize_urls'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

First question to StackOverflow--please bear with me.  I'm having problems getting started with the Stringex gem. I put "gem 'stringex'" in my Gemfile and then ran bundle install, which worked fine. In the console, I can now access the to_url method from stringex:

```
"will this work".to_url --> "will-this-work"
```

However, when I try the initialize_urls method, I get this error:

```
Message.all.each{|p| p.initialize_urls} -->  NoMethodError: undefined method `initialize_urls' for #<Message:0x007f842150b368>
```

Below is my message.rb

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_url :content

  def to_param
    url
  end 
end
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong because I seem to be able to access part of the stringex Gem (to_url), but not the other parts?

Comment: `initialize_urls` is a class method, not an instance method. You're calling it for all instances of Message. But it should be called on `Message` itself.

Comment: Thanks...you're right that was the problem. Weird, because I was just copying/pasting from https://github.com/rsl/stringex, where they had the command Post.all.each{|p| p.initialize_urls}